# SQL with subquery WHERE condition is empty

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am hoping someone can advise on what is wrong.

```
SELECT sms.id FROM sms INNER JOIN screens ON sms.screen_id = screens.id WHERE screens.experience_id = '108';
```

AND

```
SELECT id FROM sms
WHERE screen_id IN (SELECT id FROM screens WHERE experience_id = 108 )
```

... returns an empty row, but there are rows that should be returned.

To clarify...

```
SELECT id FROM sms
```

... returns all rows in SMS

```
SELECT id FROM sms
WHERE screen_id IN (SELECT id FROM screens)
```

... returns all rows in SMS and

```
SELECT id FROM screens WHERE experience_id = 108
```

... returns all rows from screens with that id.

SQL to make the tables...

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `screens` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `device_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `experience_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `persona_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `socialPost` text NOT NULL,
  `socialLinkHeadline` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `socialLinkDescription` text NOT NULL,
  `socialLink` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `socialAction` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `bgcolor` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '#fff',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=472 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sms` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `source` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `screen_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=20 ;
```

A GIF of me running these queries to verify is here: https://ibb.co/gzPFsd

I am at a loss and can see that people can't replicate, thanks!

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Comment: And maybe read up on JOINs

Comment: I have added more helpful information to the post, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what's wrong in your query but you can do that using join as well.

```
SELECT sms.id FROM sms INNER JOIN screens ON sms.screen_id = screens.id WHERE screens.experience_id = '108';
```

Comment: Thanks, I have the same results using your query there. I will continue to investigate, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your query works fine , here's the proof.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SMS,SCREENS;
CREATE TABLE SMS(ID INT, SCREEN_ID INT);
CREATE TABLE SCREENS(ID INT, EXPERIENCE_ID INT);

INSERT INTO SMS VALUES (1,1),(2,2);
INSERT INTO SCREENS VALUES(1,108),(2,100);

SELECT id FROM sms
WHERE screen_id IN (SELECT id FROM screens WHERE experience_id = 108 );

+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Assuming that my data model and yours are the same.

Comment: It is not working more and is as I outline above. I can't understand why this is happening.

Not enough character spaces in comments to paste in the SQL code for creating the tables. I will keep trying, thanks

Comment: Gif of running queries: 
https://ibb.co/gzPFsd

I have added context to original post